# Update enquiries for C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, linq, datagridview

```
private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (testEntities Setupctx = new testEntities())
    {

        var toBeUpdatedStart = txtStart.Text;
        var toBeUpdatedStop = txtStop.Text;
        shifthour updateShiftStart;
        shifthour updateShiftStop;
        updateShiftStart = Setupctx.shifthours.FirstOrDefault(u => u.shiftTiming_start == toBeUpdatedStart);
        updateShiftStop = Setupctx.shifthours.FirstOrDefault(p => p.shiftTiming_stop == toBeUpdatedStop);
        updateShiftStart.shiftTiming_start = txtStart.Text;  <-- error prompt here
        updateShiftStop.shiftTiming_stop = txtStop.Text;
        Setupctx.SaveChanges();
        txtStart.Text = "";
        txtStop.Text = "";
        MessageBox.Show("Shift Timing Has Been Updated.");
    }
}
```

Hi, anyone have any idea what's wrong with this code? 
More information : 
This is to edit shift hours for staff. When I entered the new start and stop time, the error prompt out and say "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (testEntities Setupctx = new testEntities())
            {
                int ID = Int32.Parse(lblID.Text);
                var SHquery = (from sh in Setupctx.shifthours
                             where sh.idShiftHours == ID
                             select sh).First();

```
                SHquery.shiftTiming_start = txtStart.Text;
                SHquery.shiftTiming_stop = txtStop.Text;
                Setupctx.SaveChanges();
                txtStart.Text = "";
                txtStop.Text = "";
                this.Edit_Shift_Hours_Load(null, EventArgs.Empty);
                MessageBox.Show("Shift Timing Has Been Updated.");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `updateShiftStart` is null that is why you are getting this exception. Since you are using `FirstOrDefault` it would return the first result or null if none is found, and your search is not returning anything that is why updateShiftStart is assigned null an thus the exception. You may put a check before using the value.

```
if(updateShiftStart != null)
  {
    updateShiftStart.shiftTiming_start = txtStart.Text;
  }
```

Your comparison, `(u => u.shiftTiming_start == toBeUpdatedStart);` is probably. Since you are comparing strings you may use

```
updateShiftStart = Setupctx.shifthours.FirstOrDefault(u => u.shiftTiming_start.Equals(toBeUpdatedStart));
```

You may use `StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase` to ignore case in Equals

Comment: Habib.OSU i tried your way and it prompts me the Message but doesn't change the time that I updated. Why is this so?

Comment: Because its not going in the check, that means your object is still null. I am not sure what is wrong with your data, but your statement FirstOrDefault is returning you null

Answer (score 0):

The variables updateShiftStart and updateShiftStop are set using a query using FirstOrDefault() which can result in a NULL reference.

Comment: It 's interesting that you would remark on my answer like you did, but answer the exact same thing.

Comment: I tried setting First instead of FirstOrDefault but the result is the same.

Comment: @Ioannis Karadimas, my apologies, I read your answer wrong. I thought you said that updateShiftStart is initially NULL, and that because of that, the second line fails. My mistake, I'll remove my comment.

Answer (score 0):

`updateShiftStart` is null, which means the line

```
 updateShiftStart = Setupctx.shifthours.FirstOrDefault(u => u.shiftTiming_start == toBeUpdatedStart);
```

fails to return an object. `FirstOrDefault` will find the first item it can, or null. If your code absolutely requires that `updateShiftStart` is not null, you should check after the operation, or use `First` instead.

Comment: @Maarten sure, but I'm guessing your Linq returns `null`, which is valid given that you use `FirstOrDefault`.